# getrowcellvalue get the value but not fill in textbox using object

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm using `gridcontrol` of `devexpres`. I want to fill an object like `textedit`,`datepicker`,`checkbox` etc. from the `gridcontrol`, for that I had to make a function like `DGSearch_CellClick`; but there is a problem when I get the value, can't set it in objects like `textedit`,`datepicker`,`checkbox`.

Below is my code:

```
public void DGSearch_CellClick(GridView GView, object[] ConMast, int CurrRow)
{
    try
    {
         for (int i = 0; i <= ConMast.Length - 1; i++)
         {
             ConMast[i] = GView.GetRowCellValue(CurrRow, GView.Columns[i]).ToString();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}    

public void Search(int k)
{
    try
    {
        // vbcls.DGSearch_CellClick(GViewSearch, new Control[] { TxtMstID, DtDate, TxtJno, DtSite, TxtPartyCode, TxtCompanyCode, TxtTypeCode, TxtArticalCode, TxtJanCharniCode, TxtProcessCode, TxtRgPer, TxtPoPer, TxtManufacturerSize, TxtLsWt, TxtMainCutno, TxtCutNo, TxtRemarks, ChkAutoCut, ChkAutoKno }, k);

        vbcls.DGSearch_CellClick(GViewSearch, new object[] { TxtMstID.Text, DtDate.EditValue, TxtJno.Text, DtSite.EditValue, TxtPartyCode.Text, TxtCompanyCode.Text, TxtTypeCode.Text, TxtArticalCode.Text, TxtJanCharniCode.Text, TxtProcessCode.Text, TxtRgPer.Text, TxtPoPer.Text, TxtManufacturerSize.Text, TxtLsWt.Text, TxtMainCutno.Text, TxtCutNo.Text, TxtRemarks.Text, ChkAutoCut.Checked, ChkAutoKno.Checked }, k);
        FillData();
        GCSearch.Visible = false;
        BtnEdit.Focus();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without any investigation, I wonder if you shouldn't pass ConMast by reference as in `public void DGSearch_CellClick(GridView GView, ref object[] ConMast, int CurrRow)` ?

Answer (score 0):

While you certainly can edit values directly within a grid, I think your best bet is to make your grid databound, to a DataTable if you have to, but preferably to a collection of objects.

The addition of a `BindingSource` component will give you one more tool, and I recomment its use.  For example, if you bind your collection to your binding source and bind your binding source to the grid, then any changes to the focused row in the grid will automatically update `bindSource.Current`.

Here is what that might look like:

```
gridDgSearch.DataSource = bindDgSearch;

List<DgSearch> dgSearchList = DgSearchCrud.GetAll();
bindDgSearch = dgSearchList;
```

Now, rather than trying to find items in the grid, simply iterate through your collection.  Rather than updating items in the grid, update them in the collection and refresh the grid.

Also, `e.RowHandle` in many of the grid events will indicate the row in question, meaning this:

```
(DgSearch)gridDgSearchView.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
```

Will give you the entire object for that row (if the event arg doesn't already).

If you can elaborate more on where the contents of the grid come from, what you want to do with it, etc, it might help narrow down how you can handle it with this approach.